# Why is the size of a minimum vertex cover always greater than or equal to a maximal matching?

Tags: graph-theory, duality-theorems, discrete-optimization, matching-theory

The topic I am dealing with right now is a 2-approximation algorithm for the minimum vertex cover. The proof seems fairly simple but I don't understand one assumption that is made.

It is the assumption that the size of a minimal vertex cover is always greater than or equal to the size of a maximal matching.

Imagine a graph with 6 vertices which represents a path like this:

1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 - 6

Here the minimum vertex cover is 2, you get it by choosing the vertices "2" and "5" but the maximal matching could be {(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)} and so the upper assumption doesn't hold. I miss something...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vertices $\{2,5\}$ do not cover edge $(3,4)$, so $\{2,5\}$ is not a vertex cover.